# Ubuntu 16.04 server network goes to sleep

Tags: linux, debian, networkmanager

I have a linux server (Ubuntu 16.04) which I access through vSphere client. I have defined static interface looking like this:

```
auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
  address 91.185.215.206
  netmask 255.255.255.224
  gateway 91.185.215.193
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

I've also installed NetworkManager and set managed to true, since I am using static configuration.

The problem is, that after approximately 40 seconds after boot (or after network-manager restart), I loose connection to and from the server (I determine that with ping from a third server to this one).

I then again recover the connection either by initiating ping from this very server to, for example google, or by restarting network-manager. As if network went to sleep and needs to be 'waken up' by something (in this case ping to google).

But the thing is that even ping to google goes stale after approximately 40 seconds.

Any ideas?